# parse soap response returns null

Tags: java, parsing, soap

```
 <env:Body   env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <m:getUserMusicResponse    xmlns:m="http://www.myservicetest.com/Test">
   <myList     soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[405]">
    <string      xsi:type="xsd:string">abc.mp3</string>
    <string      xsi:type="xsd:string">cdf.mp3</string>
    <string      xsi:type="xsd:string">jap.mp3</string>
    <string      xsi:type="xsd:string">xyz.mp3</string>
    <string      xsi:type="xsd:string">zab.mp3</string>
        ....
   </myList>
```

I wanted to parse above list but I keep getting null as array.

```
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();   
        response = postRequest(soapUrl, requestBody);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(response));
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("myList");
        for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node x = nodeList.item(i);
            myList.add(x.getNodeValue());             
        }
```

myList prints [null]

What is wrong with my code? or how do I parse above list?

Comment: Have you tried printing in the for loop to see if any iterations happen?

Comment: array size is 1 and [myList: null]

Comment: Ah I see now. NodeList, contains only 1 item. that item is the <mylist> object. within that object is all of your <string>'s

Comment: not sure if i am following. 1 item is null [null]

Comment: I tried using your code too, and even `doc` is null. I think there is a problem with the InputSource.